# PHP search through CSV misses first character of each line

Tags: php, csv

I'm having a .csv with about a hundred lines, each line looking like this:

```
lastname, firstname, role, ...
```

I'm searching through the `.csv` with the script provided below which works fine.

The only problem is that it returns only matches from the second character of the lastname on. So if I type some `firstname -> match, role -> match, astname -> match, lastname -> no match`. Obviously the first character of each line is ignored, but I don't know why. Also PHP does not show ä, ö, ü characters but finds them in the `.csv`.

```
<?php
//returns an array containing each line as value of another array
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('data.csv'));
//get the search parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

if(strlen($q) > 0) {
  $hint="";
  foreach($csv as $line){
    //if the line contains the search string, append it to the resulting string
    if(strpos($line[0], $q, 0) != FALSE) {
        $hint = $hint."<p>".$line[0]."</p>";
    }
  }
}

// Set output to "no suggestion" if no hint was found
// or to the correct values
if ($hint == "") {
  $response = "no suggestions";
} else {
  $response = $hint;
}

//output the response
echo $response;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution to:** PHP Loose Comparison and `strpos` Zero Index Problem

Limit your conditional statement to an exact type comparison, using `!==`:

```
if(strpos($line[0], $q, 0) !== FALSE) {
    $hint = $hint."<p>".$line[0]."</p>";
}
```

PHP `strpos` uses a zero-based string index, so it's actually matching *lastname* at position `0` and returns that value, which is loosely interpreted as `FALSE`. However, using a strict type comparison, such as `===` and `!==` limits your conditional statement to look for a match of *type* (boolean in this case) and value.

In the olden days of programming (when typewriters were used) I resorted to this hack: `strpos("_".$string, $match)`.

Comment: I actually had a notion that this might be it. However, I didn't try for it, since I didn't see any reason why this should solve the issue. Now I now, and it was worth asking. Thank you :)